# iPad texture loading differences (32-bit vs. 64-bit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, core-graphics

I am working on a drawing application and I am noticing significant differences in textures loaded on a 32-bit iPad vs. a 64-bit iPad.

Here is the texture drawn on a 32-bit iPad:

[image]

Here is the texture drawn on a 64-bit iPad:

[image]

The 64-bit is what I desire, but it seems like maybe it is losing some data?

I create a default brush texture with this code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(64, 64));
CGContextRef defBrushTextureContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(defBrushTextureContext);

size_t num_locations = 3;
CGFloat locations[3] = { 0.0, 0.8, 1.0 };
CGFloat components[12] = { 1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0,
    1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0,
    1.0,1.0,1.0, 0.0 };
CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

CGPoint myCentrePoint = CGPointMake(32, 32);
float myRadius = 20;

CGGradientDrawingOptions options = kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation;
CGContextDrawRadialGradient (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myGradient, myCentrePoint,
                             0, myCentrePoint, myRadius,
                             options);

CFRelease(myGradient);
CFRelease(myColorspace);
UIGraphicsPopContext();

[self setBrushTexture:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And then actually set the brush texture like this:

```
-(void) setBrushTexture:(UIImage*)brushImage{
// save our current texture.
currentTexture = brushImage;

// first, delete the old texture if needed
if (brushTexture){
    glDeleteTextures(1, &brushTexture);
    brushTexture = 0;
}

// fetch the cgimage for us to draw into a texture
CGImageRef brushCGImage = brushImage.CGImage;

// Make sure the image exists
if(brushCGImage) {
    // Get the width and height of the image
    GLint width = CGImageGetWidth(brushCGImage);
    GLint height = CGImageGetHeight(brushCGImage);

    // Texture dimensions must be a power of 2. If you write an application that allows users to supply an image,
    // you'll want to add code that checks the dimensions and takes appropriate action if they are not a power of 2.

    // Allocate  memory needed for the bitmap context
    GLubyte* brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    // Use  the bitmatp creation function provided by the Core Graphics framework.
    CGContextRef brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushCGImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    // After you create the context, you can draw the  image to the context.
    CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushCGImage);
    // You don't need the context at this point, so you need to release it to avoid memory leaks.
    CGContextRelease(brushContext);

    // Use OpenGL ES to generate a name for the texture.
    glGenTextures(1, &brushTexture);
    // Bind the texture name.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture);
    // Set the texture parameters to use a minifying filter and a linear filer (weighted average)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // Specify a 2D texture image, providing the a pointer to the image data in memory
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);
    // Release  the image data; it's no longer needed
    free(brushData);
}
}
```

**Update:**

I've updated CGFloats to be GLfloats with no success. Maybe there is an issue with this rendering code?

```
if(frameBuffer){
    // draw the stroke element
    [self prepOpenGLStateForFBO:frameBuffer];
    [self prepOpenGLBlendModeForColor:element.color];
    CheckGLError();
}

// find our screen scale so that we can convert from
// points to pixels
GLfloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;

// fetch the vertex data from the element
struct Vertex* vertexBuffer = [element generatedVertexArrayWithPreviousElement:previousElement forScale:scale];

glLineWidth(2);

// if the element has any data, then draw it
if(vertexBuffer){
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(struct Vertex), &vertexBuffer[0].Position[0]);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(struct Vertex), &vertexBuffer[0].Color[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(struct Vertex), &vertexBuffer[0].Texture[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (GLint)[element numberOfSteps] * (GLint)[element numberOfVerticesPerStep]);
    CheckGLError();
}

if(frameBuffer){
    [self unprepOpenGLState];
}
```

The vertex struct is the following:

```
struct Vertex{
    GLfloat Position[2];    // x,y position
    GLfloat Color [4];      // rgba color
    GLfloat Texture[2];    // x,y texture coord
};
```

**Update:**

The issue does not actually appear to be 32-bit, 64-bit based, but rather something different about the A7 GPU and GL drivers. I found this out by running a 32-bit build and 64-bit build on the 64-bit iPad. The textures ended up looking exactly the same on both builds of the app.

Comment: `CGFloat` is single-precision on 32-bit iOS targets and double-precision on 64-bit. You are not using this typedef anywhere that interacts directly with GL, are you? GL, on the other hand, always uses 32-bit for `GLfloat` and this sort of thing happens if you mix-and-match typedefs.

Comment: I don't see anything that immediately looks wrong with what you posted. I suspect @Andon is right — check for `CGFloat` use elsewhere in your code, particularly where you define the framebuffer your brush is drawing into.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that, but I am still noticing the same behavior. I've updated the question with further explanation.

Comment: Are you using a shader to render the texture? If so please post it and check the precision in it. 64 bit iPads ignore lowp and use mediump instead which can sometimes result in render differences.

Comment: I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1, so, unfortunately, no shaders.

Comment: It does look like a precision problem to me. OpenGL ES 1.1 is emulated on the A7 GPU (meaning internally it is using shaders). Can you post more of your OpenGL setup including blend states used? Also you should set GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER to be linear at the same time that you set GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER.

Answer (score 1):

I would like you to check two things.

1. Check your alpha blending logic(or option) in OpenGL.
2. Check your interpolation logic which is proportional to velocity of dragging.

It seems you don't have second one or not effective which is required to drawing app

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is in the texture but in the frame buffer to which you composite the line elements.

Your code fragments look like you draw segments by segment, so there are several overlapping segments drawn on top of each other. If the depth of the frame buffer is low there will be artifacts, especially in the lighter regions of the blended areas.

You can check the frame buffer using Xcode's OpenGL debugger. Activate it by running your code on the device and click the little "Capture OpenGL ES Frame" button: [image: Capture OpenGL ES Frame].

Select a "glBindFramebuffer" command in the "Debug Navigator" and look at the frame buffer description in the console area:

[image: frame buffer description]

The interesting part is the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INTERNAL_FORMAT`.

Comment: I am seeing the same internal format as you, but what are you recommending I do?

Comment: @Jordan Do you see the same internal format on both devices?

Comment: Yes, I see the same format on 32-bit and 64-bit iPads.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the problem is in the blending mode you use when composing different image passes. I assume that you upload the texture for display only, and keep the in-memory image where you composite different drawing operations, or you read-back the image content using glReadPixels ? 
Basically your second images appears like a straight-alpha image drawn like a pre-multiplied alpha image.
To be sure that it isn't a texture problem, save a NSImage to file before uploading to the texture, and check that the image is actually correct.